# dynamic chained select using json in spring mvc

Tags: jquery, json, spring-mvc

I am working in spring mvc framework and project have a requirement to create a dynamic chained select using json. Project required that request go to the server only once.Anyone have some idea how to implement this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use DWR or jQuery with Spring for JSON responses.
And If you are using Spring 3 then this URL http://blog.springsource.com/2010/01/25/ajax-simplifications-in-spring-3-0/ will guide you how to use jQuery for JSON response with Spring 3.